# Planets days and orbital period

Tags: planets, xenobiology, orbital-mechanics, day-night

Lets say there's planet that has an orbital period of 7 earth years and days that last about two hours. What created the orbital period and days of the planet to be different from earth and what primitive life could develop on this world?

Comment: What kind of life? A full evolutionary tree is far to broad to answer here.

Comment: Welcome to the site Hotdog.  Your question is on-topic for the site but as it stands it is overly broad.  You should separate your two questions (how the orbit was set up and could life develop).  You are also likely going to need to provide more information about your planet.  Check out the [help] for more info on writing good questions and answers.

Comment: This question is NOT too broad.  It's a very pleasing width.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is a rocky, approximately-Earthlike-in-all-other-respects planet since you're asking about life.

The long orbital period means your planet is further away from its star; I don't know the relevant math, but if we use the Sun as a baseline your planet would probably show up somewhere between Mars and Jupiter (source: eyeballing from [here](http://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/planets_table.html); for a 23-year orbit you'd be between Jupiter and Saturn, closer to Saturn).

On its own this would make your planet rather chilly. On the other hand, the main thing that comes to mind as a possibility for a two-hour day is, er, massive (angled on average) asteroid/comet bombardment, which has the convenient* side effect of heating the planet up.

*Convenient for those not already living there, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

based on the orbital period, this planet is pretty far from its star. To still be in abitable zone, the star has to shine really a lot, kind of a blue giant, meaning it won't live long enough to sustain life.